# Mail Compose View Controller is delayed in swift for ios objective c?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, email

I have this code to send feedback email , it works fine however the email container takes some time to show title and receiver attributes, Moreover typing in the email is disabled for like 4 seconds then is becomes active. 
here is the code:

```
   @IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}

func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    var mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property
    mailComposerVC.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var font : UIFont = UIFont(name: "DroidArabicKufi", size: 12)!
    mailComposerVC.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["support@company.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("subject")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}
```

Comment: i think it's only for first time for initializing purpose.

Comment: Is it on the simulator?? are you getting the same on the device??

Comment: @Rushi no it happens every time I use it

Comment: @satheeshwaran yes I am testing it on the simulator , I will check on the device soon and see the result [ my phone is iOS9.2 beta whereas XCode is not a beta ]

Comment: @iShaalan Mailcomposer on simulator is always a bit slow you don't have to worry about it even I have faced such issues but on the device stuff works well.

Comment: @satheeshwaran I will accept this as an answer, Just move it to the answers section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally **MFMailComposeViewController** is a little slow on the simulator but you don't have to worry about it. This happens mostly the first time you fire the simulator and later it is fast.The same happens with **UIActivityViewController** to open share and action extensions. My suggestion is, it would not be a problem with your code, just test the same on the device mostly it should work fine.